# Online web form builder

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, html, forms

I would like to be able to provide a relatively basic HTML form builder for an application I work on. Our application allows users to use their own HTML forms, however for them to actually make these forms, we have to rely on them either being technically minded or on finding some online tools to do the work for them (and even then, our forms are slightly customised so they would need to edit the generated content)

I’m looking for a graphically oriented way for (non-technical) users to build an HTML form.

Ideal features:

- Free
- JavaScript based
- Open Source (and be under a licence which allows editing)
- Graphical form building with a good range of options
- Outputs either raw HTML or something equivalent
- Returns the form itself, not the data (I am NOT looking for web services which let you build and host your forms on their servers, I just want to be able to generate the HTML itself)

I have looked around and found [Formbuilder](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder) ([demo](http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/)), but it seems rather buggy and it only outputs the raw details as JSON, rather than actually producing a form.

Does anyone know of any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the jquery plugin called [jQuery formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/) and the repo for it is [available here](https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder).

I'm not seeing a release licence like GPL, or MIT, at this time, so it may not be suitable for some projects. It does look to be pretty active, which is a plus.

EDIT--
The licence is GNU and can be found here: http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/license/

Comment: I'll swap over the accepted answer as that definitely looks like the best option, I wish that'd been around and in the state it is now back when I asked this!

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this [Bootstrap Form Builder](http://bootsnipp.com/forms) ([GitHub project here](https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder)) that seems to do exactly what I need.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com) sounds like what you need. After building your form with drag and drop tools, it will give you an HTML snippet to paste on your website. The free version allows 3 forms. It organizes your responses on a spreadsheet that you can export to Excel or CSV.

[image: Wufoo Example]

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear, I don't want someone else hosting a form for me. Their builder looks great, but I doubt it's available as an open source component that I can use in our project.